# Rails user mailer not sending emails in production

Tags: ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sendgrid

I have a user model with a method that should send a welcome email when a user submits their email address. After setting up sendgrid, no emails are fired when I submit an email.

Here's my production.rb code:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['DEFAULT_MAILER_HOST'] }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Parts of the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: {
    with: /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/i,
    message: 'Invalid email format.'
  }

  after_create :send_welcome_email

  private

  def send_welcome_email
    UserMailer.delay.signup_email(self)
  end
end
```

The user mail code:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Example <welcome@example.com>"

  def signup_email(user)
    @user = user

    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Thank you for joining!")
  end
end
```

The heroku logs

```
2019-08-04T20:23:22.053028+00:00 app[web.1]:  (2.0ms)  COMMIT
2019-08-04T20:23:22.054171+00:00 app[web.1]:  (0.6ms)  BEGIN
2019-08-04T20:23:22.056282+00:00 app[web.1]: User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'max.ston@protonmail.com' LIMIT 1
2019-08-04T20:23:22.058729+00:00 app[web.1]: User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."referral_code" IS NULL LIMIT 1
2019-08-04T20:23:22.067815+00:00 app[web.1]: User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "49af69325b"]]
2019-08-04T20:23:22.072798+00:00 app[web.1]: SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at", "referral_code") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "max.ston@protonmail.com"], ["created_at", "2019-08-04 20:23:22.059018"], ["updated_at", "2019-08-04 20:23:22.059018"], ["referral_code", "49af69325b"]]
2019-08-04T20:23:22.109242+00:00 app[web.1]: SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("handler", "run_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["handler", "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject: !ruby/class 'UserMailer'\nmethod_name: :signup_email\nargs:\n- !ruby/object:User\n  raw_attributes:\n    email: max.ston@protonmail.com\n    id: '3'\n    referral_code: 49af69325b\n    created_at: &1 2019-08-04 20:23:22.059018923 Z\n    updated_at: *1\n    referrer_id: \n  attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet\n    attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash\n      types:\n        id: &3 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer\n          precision: \n          scale: \n          limit: \n          range: !ruby/range\n            begin: -2147483648\n            end: 2147483648\n            excl: true\n        email: &2 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::String\n          precision: \n          scale: \n          limit: \n        referral_code: *2\n        referrer_id: *3\n        created_at: &5 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter\n          subtype: &4 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::DateTime\n            precision: \n            scale: \n            limit: \n        updated_at: &6 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter\n          subtype: *4\n      values:\n        id: \n        email: \n        referral_code: \n        referrer_id: \n        created_at: \n        updated_at: \n      additional_types: {}\n      materialized: true\n      delegate_hash:\n        email: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser\n          name: email\n          value_before_type_cast: max.ston@protonmail.com\n          type: *2\n          value: max.ston@protonmail.com\n        id: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser\n          name: id\n          value_before_type_cast: '3'\n          type: *3\n          value: 3\n        referral_code: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser\n          name: referral_code\n          value_before_type_cast: 49af69325b\n          type: *2\n          value: 49af69325b\n        created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser\n          name: created_at\n          value_before_type_cast: *1\n          type: *5\n          value: 2019-08-04 20:23:22.059018923 Z\n        updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromUser\n          name: updated_at\n          value_before_type_cast: *1\n          type: *6\n          value: 2019-08-04 20:23:22.059018923 Z\n        referrer_id: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase\n          name: referrer_id\n          value_before_type_cast: \n          type: *3\n  new_record: false\n  active_record_yaml_version: 0\n"], ["run_at", "2019-08-04 20:23:22.105001"], ["created_at", "2019-08-04 20:23:22.105297"], ["updated_at", "2019-08-04 20:23:22.105297"]]
2019-08-04T20:23:22.112611+00:00 app[web.1]:  (1.8ms)  COMMIT
2019-08-04T20:23:22.113058+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://enigmatic-temple-XXXXX.herokuapp.com/refer-a-friend
2019-08-04T20:23:22.113229+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 70ms (ActiveRecord: 16.4ms)
```

Comment: Are there any entries in the log files, when you create a user? The `delay` in `UserMailer.delay.signup_email` implies that you are using some kind of background jobs. How did you configure those jobs runners?

Comment: I ran "heroku rake jobs:work" and got this message:

```
UserMailer#signup_email: processed outbound mail in 20.7ms
[Worker(host:bb4cc50d-c1fc-475a-b1ff-2004358ed429 pid:4)] Job UserMailer.signup_email (id=1) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ActionView::Template::Error: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
2019-08-05T13:55:12+0000: [Worker(host:bb4cc50d-c1fc-475a-b1ff-2004358ed429 pid:4)] Job UserMailer.signup_email (id=1) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ActionView::Template::Error: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

Comment: can you post full backtrace errors in your question?  Looks like the error is telling you where the problem is.

Comment: @MaxRah it says you have an error in your View. Please, post the view file and the full stack trace.

Comment: Fixed the issue. There were several syntax errors in the `user mailer` view. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the `signup_email.html.erb` file. The image source links had errors so I changed the line:

`<img src="<%= Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options %>`

to this:

`<img src="<%= Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] %>`

This is because default_url_options is a `hash`.